# how to add/edit contents of "view details" tab of a custom word press plugin in admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDC74.jpg)

this is what I've found so far **https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_api/**
but I could only fetch the plugin's data Object by its slug
and I need to find a way to add or edit this content (the other way around)
any suggestions?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Dja.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

### Actually, you shouldn't change this area!

but using the Akismet plugin as an example, I would edit the `akismet.php` file in the

*`"wp-content/plugins/akismet"`*

folder...

hope to have helped you.

Comment: Thanx a lot  , i'll give it a try